# Shift menu vertically and display sub menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write one vertical menu like in [this website](http://www.icicibank.com/) . On hover the vertical menu should shift marginally to the right side and should display the sub menu.

I have been failed to accomplish this.
Please help me :(

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
<style>
   .apear
   {
   width:200px;
   height:300px;
   background-color:pink;
   float:right;
   display:none;
   }
  .one
  {
   background-color:yellow;
   height:100px;
   width:100px
   }
  .two
{
background-color:blue;
height:100px;
width:100px
}
.three
{
background-color:green;
height:100px;
width:100px
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="apear">
</div>
<div style="float:right">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add to your question the code where you _failed to accomplish this_.

Comment: can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: this is my css <style>
#static_right_vertical {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  margin-top: -10em;
}
#static_right_vertical:hover{
 position:fixed;
 margin-right:200px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 height:60px;
 }
#square {
 width: 200px;
 height: 85px;
 background:#053c6d;
}
#square1 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 85px;
 background:#f5821f;
}
</style>

Comment: this is my html code:  
                    <div id="static_right_vertical">
                    <div id="square1">
                    <li>Log In</li></div>
                    <hr> <div id="square">
                    <li>Human Resources</li></div>
                    <hr>
                    <div id="square">
<li>Recruitment drive</li></div><hr>
<div id="square">
<li>Product</li></div><hr>
<div id="square">
<li>Case studies</li></div>
</div>               When i hover the menu it shifts but continuously blinks

Comment: edit your question and add the code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution, I used JQuery:

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="apear">
</div>

<div style="float:right">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.apear
{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:pink;
  float:right;
  display:none;
}
.one
{
  background-color:yellow;
  height:100px;
  width:100px
}
.two
{
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px
}
.three
{
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
  width:100px
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".one").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".apear").show(500);
    });
  $(".apear").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".apear").hide(500);
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9fq9jw6/)

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this using css only

Comment: Hi Ali Seyfi, I tried this code in fiddle it's working but i wrote the same code and tested it in browser it's not working!!!

Comment: I have Used JQuery you should include it by <script src=""></script>
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: I have added this line under head section <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>. but still doesn't works

Comment: Hi Ali, I have successfully developed this menu but the problem is when i am trying to select the sub menu option it's getting collapsed to it's initial phase. For example when i am hovering on menu it's coming up by shifting the menu to the right side. But when i trying to choose the sub menu option, the sub menu disappear. Any suggestion.